# deleting headers in lyx

Tags: lyx

hi I want to delete the "Généralités sur le plasma" and add chapter 1 before the sentence "Spectroscopie sur plasma induit par laser" [image]

Comment: This is like the fourth question you are asking today on actually quite basic stuff both in terms of Lyx and LaTeX. Not that I mind, this site exists for helping people out, but in your case I highly recommend that you spend some time googling for lyx tutorials to get you started instead of using other people to explain all of this to you one question at a time.

Comment: Also note that LyX has a lot of documentation in the Help menu, and if you happen to be interested our French translation of the documentation is quite impressive. We also have a lyx-fr mailing list that is very low traffic.

Comment: Thanks for your advises all ,I will check it ,but I have to write  my thesis at the same time  so I didnt get enough time to check the basics.